# Keep Python script running as a TCP socket server on AWS machine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, tcp

I need to deploy a Python script on a AWS machine with Ubuntu server 18.04. 
In the script there is a TCP server using a custom TCP port (let's say the 9999), which handles the clients' requests in different threads.
The problem is that I don't know which could be the best practice to keep this script running if there is any problem (the main TCP server thread dies for whatever reason).
Furthermore, I don't really know which could be the best practice to run this kind of script in the AWS EC2 system.

So far I am manually starting the script via SSH. Everything in the script logic works well, the problem is how to start and keep running such script.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) suite. It can be used to manage the status of your script. It can restart the script if it dies, or if the node is rebooted.

Here's an example service.

Create the file below in this location: /lib/systemd/system/example.service

```
[Unit]
Description=A short description of the script.

[Service]
Type=simple
# Script location
ExecStart=/path/to/some/script.py
# Restart the script in all circumstances (e.g If it exits successfully, fails or crashes).
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then set the service to start automatically on boot and start the service:

```
chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/example.service
systemctl enable example
systemctl start example
```

There are a lot of resources available if you want to learn more about systemd. I'd suggest the links below:

[0] https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/

[1] https://github.com/torfsen/python-systemd-tutorial

[2] https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/start-service-at-boot/#create-a-custom-systemd-service

[3] https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

As for general best practices, it is difficult to provide advice without knowing more about your script. It is not recommended to use the python HTTPServer module for Production workloads, because it only implements basic security checks.